# ckan.toolkit.redirect_to does not redirect

Tags: python-2.7, ckan

I'm currently developing an ckan extension, where i need to redirect to a url on a different domain.

In my plugin i defined a custom action function:

```
@side_effect_free
def download_json(context, data_dict):
    toolkit.redirect_to('http://my.json-builder.com?id=1234')
```

But when i call this endpoint i just get following response:

[response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nVBa.png)

So i assume that the action function is called, but the redirect_to call does not redirect to the url i defined.

Thanks for your help!
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to figure out what you're trying to accomplish but here's a few things I hope will help.

## Short Answer:

No, you can't redirect from an API endpoint in CKAN. The endpoint response in CKAN is built up and expects certain things from your action. Your action should return some kind of result. In your case it's returning nothing but trying to redirect. A logic action function with `IActions` is not the same as a Blueprint or pylons controller action.

See [Making an API request](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/api/#making-an-api-request) docs, specifically the breakdown of an API response in CKAN.  Also, you can review the [pylons implementation](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/b5aeb795e0b1624238df1190e24ec6b1228b67d6/ckan/controllers/api.py#L207) that builds up the API response or the [flask blueprints implementation](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/70128fbaaf555cafc6642fd462ec0592b0234bbb/ckan/views/api.py#L290).

## More Info to help with your approach:

You say you are trying to call an endpoint that **redirects** a user to a different domain url. Based on this consider the following:

1. The first thing I thought you wanted was to have a url that someone goes to through the web interface of your site and are redirected to another site. In this case your example code of `toolkit.redirect_to('http://my.json-builder.com?id=1234')` makes sense and works for a custom controller action using/implemented with [`IRoutes`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html?highlight=IRoutes#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IRoutes) or if you're using flask then [`IBlueprint`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IBlueprint). A User would go to a URL on your site such as `http://localhost.com/download_json` and be redirected to the new URL/site in their browser.
2. If you are intending this to be an API call for other users this starts to feel a little bit odd. If a user is using your API, they would expect to get results from your site in JSON CKAN's API is designed to return JSON. Someone consuming your API endpoint would not expect to be redirected to another site e.g. if I called `http://localhost.com/api/3/action/download_json` I would expect to get a JSON object like

   `{
     help: "http://localhost/api/3/action/help_show?name=download_json",
     success: true,
     result: {
       ...
     }
   }`

   They would look for `success` to make sure the call worked and then they would use the `result` to keep moving forward with their desired processes. If you do want someone via an API to get redirect info I'd likely return the redirect url as the result e.g. `result: {'redirect_url': 'http://my.json-builder.com?id=1234'}` and document this well in your extension's API docs (e.g. why you're returning this endpoint, what you expect someone to do with it, etc).
3. If this is an API call for your own extension I'm guessing what you are trying to do is use `my.json-builder.com` to build a json of something (a dataset maybe?) and return that json as the result at your endpoint or maybe even consume the result to make something else? If that's the case, then in your function you could make the call to `my.json-builder.com`, process the results and return the results to the user. In this case, you're not actually wanting to redirect a user to a new site but instead make a call to the new site to get some results. If you actually want the results for your extension you don't need an additional endpoint. You could make the call from your extension, consume the results and return the desired object you're trying to create.

Hope this helps and sorry if I've miss-understood completely.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! The second approach was the one, i was looking for :)

Comment: for #3, how would i go about making a call to an action inside another extension?